# Powershell CSR decodieren

Tags: powershell, csr

actually I am trying to decode a CSR to check if the CSR is correct. Easiest way is to use is something like [CSR decoder](https://certlogik.com/decoder/) but I need it in Powershell for SCOCH.
First try, is to use something like `ComObject X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10` but hard to decode and buggy.
Second try is to use openssl or certutil, but I think there is only file I/O allowed and not Strings/parameter that I need.

Do you know a possibility to decode a CSR in an easier way with powershell and without file i/o?

Answer (score 0):

> Second try is to use openssl or certutil, but I think there is only file I/O allowed and not Strings/parameter that I need.

This is - fortunately for you - not true, you can pipe strings directly to `openssl` :)

```
$CSRInfo = @'
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
'@ |C:\Path\To\openssl.exe req -text -noout
```